# Как передать значение метода в функцию

Tags: c#, функции

Есть функция.

```
   public void Func()
    {
        var publicTL = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"link");
        var statuses = DynamicJson.Parse(publicTL);
        Label1.Text = statuses.data.hashRate.ToString();
    }
```

Хочу переделать ее, так что бы ее можно было вызвать примерно так `Label1.Text = Func(data.hashRate)` , т.е. я хочу передать только параметры метода. Я не понимаю даже какой тип будет функция принимать, возвращать будет строку.
Как это можно реализовать? 
PS DynamicJson библиотека для json парсинга.

Comment: `public var`? вот прямо так?

Comment: Я не силен в создании функций, поэтому за правильность не ручаюсь. Если вы знаете, поправьте, я буду рад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно получить некое значение, распарсить его и вернуть одно из его полей. Для этого опишем метод GetHashRate, который будет принимать на вход строку с адресом и возвращать строку с хэшрейтом.
UPD. Мы хотим возвращать не только HashRate, но и любое другое свойство. Для этого добавим еще один параметр `propertyName`. В нём будем передавать требуемое свойство, благо используемая библиотека позволяет использовать индексаторы:

```
    public static string GetData(string link, string propertyName)
    {
        var publicTL = GetJson(link);
        var statuses = DynamicJson.Parse(publicTL);
        return statuses["data"][propertyName].ToString();
    }

    private static string GetJson(string link)
    {
        return "{\"status\":1,\"data\":{\"hashRate\":\"119.9 MH/s\",\"block\":166479}}";
    }
```

Тут я вынес получение данных в отдельный метод (данные с Вашей ссылки не являются валидным JSON-объектом, т.к. это HTML-страница). Если будете использовать - не забудьте вернуть получение данных по ссылке.
Потом мы можем использовать результат того метода:

```
 Label1.Text = GetData(link, "hashRate");
```

Или для проверки в консоли:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetHashRate(@"http://bin.codingislove.com/giruderiwo.json", "hashRate"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetHashRate(@"http://bin.codingislove.com/giruderiwo.json", "block"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: я наверное немного не так описать суть вопроса, я хочу передавать разные аргументы в функцию, т.е. `data.hashRate` эта часть в возвращаемой строке будет меняться. Т.к. эта библиотека парсера и парсит она Json, и парситься не одно значение. Если это возможно так сделать? Надеюсь вы поняли о чем я

Comment: Не совсем. Вам нужен метод, который из произвольного JSON возьмет произвольное поле? Приведите пример данных и что Вы хотите получить разными вызовами Вашей функции.

Comment: Вот пример https://bin.codingislove.com/giruderiwo.json, я к примеру хочу получить значения `statuses.data.hashRate` и `statuses.data.block` и т.д. (значений может быть очень много), но не хочу конкретные значения описывать в функции, а хочу вызывать функцию по мере необходимости для извлечения конкретных значений, в данном случае hashRate и block. Т.е. что бы библиотека DynamicJson приняла аргументы полученные через функцию. Возможно я, что то называю не своими именами т.к. у меня хромает теория.

Comment: @PavelFedorov, ну тогда возвращайте из ф-и `DynamicJson`, а нужные поля выбирайте на клиентской стороне

Comment: @Zufir Спасибо вам, теперь я понял специфику, судя по коду она оказалась не сложной :)